# Modified version of a left Join

Tags: mysql

I have some problem in find solution to this question. I rekon my problem is not knowing how my specific need is named in mysql convention.

Anyway, here the problem.

I have 2 tables:

Table 1 is:

```
Color

id,name
1,red
2,blue
3,green
4,yellow
```

Table 2 is:

```
Item

id,name,color_id,quantity
1,knife,1,10
2,fork,1,10
3,knife,3,10
4,hammer,4,10
```

now i want to execute a query that returns me this:

```
1,red,knife,10
2,blue,null,null
3,green,knife,10
4,yellow,null,null
```

as a description of the query i would say:

1- list all the element (only once) from table 1

2- given a tool in the query (in this case knife), fill the join with the quantity.
if that object is not available in that color, leave null.

Now i tried a simple left join, that unfortunately returns me also the yellow hammer.
I tried a left join + where clause, but it does just return me the red knife, and green knife, without showing the yellow color and the blue color.

I would love to avoid subqueries.

What do you think ?

Comment: What is the primary key of the item table? i'd expect it to be `id`, but you used 3 twice.

Comment: Seems almost as if you should have a third table

Comment: items, colors, and then itemcolors that links the two and stores the quantity. With that setup, making this query can be done with outer joins.

Comment: you should be use a inner join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should have shown what you tried, but here's a query that will return the results you asked for:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, i.name, i.quantity
FROM Color c
LEFT JOIN Item i
  ON i.color_id = c.id
  AND i.name = 'knife'
```

The key here is to put 'knife' in the join condition, **not** in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: +1 Had the same idea.  You could also set a variable so it is clearer.